# What is the most important CPU price factor

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, computers, intel

I have two intel CPUS with distinct features.

- [intel i7 8550U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122589/intel-core-i7-8550u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html)
- [intel i5 8300H](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134876/intel-core-i5-8300h-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html)

Which have big performance difference with the cheaper `8300H` being higher in memory bandwidth 41 GB/s vs 37 GB/s, Bus speed of 8 GT/s vs 4 GT/s, TDP 45 W vs 15 W, and crushing the comparison in every single parameter.

[Full comparison here](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-8550U-vs-Intel-Core-i5-8300H/m320742vsm425634)

But when we come to the price, the `8550U` has a price tag of **$409.00** whereas the powerful `8300H` has a price tag of **$250.00**.

Though I tried to get reasons, I couldn't find any. what is the most important price factor for CPUs that is making such huge difference?

Comment: "Everything is worth what its purchaser will pay for it." ~Publilius Syrus

Comment: @DonFusili People are unfortunately not aware of the severe decoupling of cost versus price in today’s market.

Comment: @DonFusili so does it mean it has no any actual sensible reason? just a price manipulation of the marketing department? I's because thought I was totally missing a very important CPU parameter which singlehandedly made the big difference.

Comment: comparing CPUs' price/perf with a factor of 3 in TDP difference is pointless

Comment: I'd definitely pay a premium for a 15W TDP CPU over a 45W one. (Well, actually I wouldn't, because I wouldn't consider buying a 45W CPU notebook at all)

Comment: The 8550U is much lower power. That makes it target a completely different market.

Answer (score 4):

The most important cost factor of CPU is R&D / IP Licensing and the chip foundry.

Often, a series of processors with different performances actually have the same die implementation. The differences lie mostly in the yield of the manufacturing process.

When the silicon chips are made, there is a yield, some have small defects and while it still produces an operating chip, it will have lower performances or certain functionalities not working.

Thus once manufactured, the chips are tested and binned based on their performances and locked to a specific configuration.

It often happens that the chips on the edges of the wafer yield poorer performance as the quality of the lithographic process lowers at the edges, that coupled with other defects that can happen during manufacturing.

For example, you can have a defect in a bank of L1 cache memory, instead of throwing the chip away, you simply disable a specific memory bank and sell it with a lower L1 cache.

Concerning speed, it can be due to metalization or capacitance effects also linked to the manufacturing processes.

The price difference is simply due to the yield of the high-quality chip, market demand, availability, and what the market is ready to pay for it.

Instead of throwing out chips yielding lower performance or with slight defect, that doesn't hinder the main operation of the chip, a manufacturer prefers to sell them at lower cost, with some functionalities disabled or reduced speed.

To make a parallel to batteries, a manufacturer also has a yield. Energizer only sells the good batteries under their brand and sells lower-performing batteries cheaper under different brand names.

Comment: This is actually a surprisingly good answer. (I worked at Intel on chipset testing.)

Comment: Thank you, It makes sense that the defective ones get downgraded configuration and are sold at lower costs. But what is odd here in the question is that the much higher performing CPU is given a price tag almost half of the inferior CPU model. how could this make sense?

Comment: Market demand @Abraham

Answer (score 1):

DonFusili has the right answer: the consumer price is determined by what people will pay, so "premium" features end up much more expensive, and the same product is sold at gradually decreasing prices throughout its lifetime. The cost you pay bears very little relation to the cost of design and manufacture.

Software is completely dominated by the cost of design. Hardware is somewhere in the middle; the cost of design is huge in terms of engineer-hours, but each wafer full of chips also has a fairly high manufacturing cost (see Damien's answer).

Comment: Thank you, But here, according to what I can see the inferior performing CPU is being sold at higher price.

Comment: @Abraham I just checked the specs, keep in mind that the Kaby Lake in the i7 is compatible with newer mother board sockets such as LGA 2066, Coffee Lake requires modified LGA 1151. Also the i7 you're looking at is a low-power model, so expected to have lower specs at nominal power. They're targetted at different markets.